# Maximum length of SWD signal lines?

Tags: swd

What is the maximum length of SWD signal lines / ribbon cables? Any idea what the physical layer of SWD is?

Answer (score 2):

[No fixed length.  Link goes to design info for SWD.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0517b/Chdbgcdj.html)  Download the PDF and check section 2.12 on "JTAG signal integrity and maximum cable lengths."

Seems to depend on the device, the cable, and the clock speed as to what length you can achieve.

It appears that it is expected that the drivers are low power (mention of less than 4mA of drive current.)  You can expect trouble as the capacitance of the line increases with length.  Longer connection=higher capacitance= more problems.

The documentation also suggests that lowering the clock speed is not hard, and that adaptive clock speed would be a way to deal with long cables.

The documentation provides some more suggestions as well.

Comment: The link is about JTAG, which has no error correction, while SWD has error correction. The SWD section of the document is not going into detail about cable length.

Comment: Yep.  And it seems to be about all the specification has to say on length of cables.

Comment: The link just goes to the generic arm documentation download page. Consider adding a direct link to the pdf itself

Answer (score 0):

Well, the good ol' IDE bus gets 300+ mm out of an ordinary ribbon at 100+ MHz, SWD is slower than that so if you use a ribbon cable you should get at least 300mm